# formatting the output in a C program from two functions on same line

Tags: c

[image: expected]
The above is the current output. Below is the expected output

[image: current]

How can I modify my program to get the output in the expected format? What could be the easiest
way to do it?

Currently, I am printing the FIFO output in a separate function and Banker output in a different
function. Which is causing the display like above. Each function loops over an array and prints all   that information

Comment: You need to return all the data to the function that does the writing. Then it can loop over the two datasets in parallel, writing them each on the same line.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into questions, and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it properly.

Comment: Or collect the data in an array of another `struct` and output later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For each table, define a function which prints only one row. Then you can get the desired output by calling this function in the loop. Here is a simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(array) ((int) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0]))

struct Ta {
    const char *key;
    int value;
};

struct Tb {
    const char *key;
    int value;
};

struct Ta tableA[2];
struct Tb tableB[2];

void PrintTa(const struct Ta *x)
{
    printf("%s", x->key);
    printf("  ");
    printf("%d", x->value);
}


void PrintTb(const struct Tb *x)
{
    printf("%s", x->key);
    printf("  ");
    printf("%d", x->value);
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;

    tableA[0].key = "foo";
    tableA[0].value = 0;
    tableA[1].key = "bar";
    tableA[1].value = 1;

    tableB[0].key = "baz";
    tableB[0].value = 2;
    tableB[1].key = "qux";
    tableB[1].value = 3;

    /*vertical layout*/
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(tableA); i++) {
        PrintTa(&tableA[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(tableB); i++) {
        PrintTb(&tableB[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    putchar('\n');

    /*horizontal layout*/
    for (i = 0; i < LEN(tableA); i++) {
        PrintTa(&tableA[i]);
        printf("  ");
        PrintTb(&tableB[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will print the tables in two different layouts:

```
foo  0
bar  1
baz  2
qux  3

foo  0  baz  2
bar  1  qux  3
```